# Types and rounds in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, types, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @A as numeric(36,14) = 480
DECLARE @B as numeric(36,14) = 1

select @B/@A
select cast(@B as decimal)/cast(@A as decimal)
```

Why does the first calculation returns `0.002083` and the second one returns `0.00208333333333333`?

Isn´t `numeric(36,14)` good enough to have a good precision (just as the second query)?

If I use only `numeric`, instead of `numeric(36,14)`, I have a good precision again:

```
select cast(@B as numeric)/cast(@A as numeric)
```

Comment: [Rules for precision/scale are very complex](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale). Also don't ever cast as `numeric` or `decimal` without ***specific*** precision/scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate precision and scale by yourself using [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(v=sql.110).aspx) documentation from `SQL Server Books online`.

I tried to calculate precision and scale for your case `(operation=division, p=36, s=14)` and I got a pretty strange results...

```
precision of the result: [p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)] -> 36-14+14+max(6,14+36+1)=36+51=87
scale of the result    : [max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)]                -> max(6,14+36+1)=51
```

In this situation precision is greater than 38 and in this case (as stated in the documentation)

> *The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is
>   reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

scale must be reduced by *(87-38=)* **49**, that is *(51-49=)* **2** ...

I think that minimum scale length is **6** (because of expression *scale=[max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)]*) and it can't be reduced lower than **6** - that we have as a result (`0.002083`).

Comment: @Nizam not at all! In fact it is nothing more than an assumption,  but I think the truth is out there :)

Comment: The problem I was not even intending to solve the problem, I was trying to understand it in first place. And you gave me a good hint where to start. To be honest, I don´t know if I will go deeper on this, since it is very complicated and there is not much to gain.Maybe using float type will work for all my queries.

Comment: if you simply change type from `numeric(36,14)` to `numeric(19, 9)` you will get a perfect scale in your calculation

Answer (score 0):

Just contributing for the understanding of the problem (going deeper on @Andrey answer), the things could be tricky, depending on the order of calculations.

Consider the variables:^

```
DECLARE @A as NUMERIC(36,19) = 100
DECLARE @B as NUMERIC(36,19) = 480
DECLARE @C as NUMERIC(36,19) = 100
```

**Calculating A/B*C**

If you want to calculate A/B*C, using the formulaes, we have:

A/B is of type `NUMERIC(38,6)` --> as calculated by @Andrey

The result will be `0.208333` (with scale of `6`)
Multiplying by `100`, we will get `20.833300`

**Calculating A*C/B**

The result of A*C is `10000` of type `NUMERIC(38,6)`. Diving by C, the result will be `20.833333` of type `NUMERIC(38,6)`

Then, the result may vary depending on the order of calculation (the same problem was pointed in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale).